# How to check if the column contains values that are not numbers but also exclude blanks?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Title is pretty much the question, but I'm trying to check if there's an efficient way to check if two columns (not infinite) contain values that are not numbers.

I've tried to use something like

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A), IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B), "", "errB"), "errA"))

but the problem with this is that it also counts blanks and I feel like expanding the formula by using <> to exclude blanks is inefficient.

any tips and guidance are appreciated!

Comment: can you give better explanation of the expected results? letter:number=?; number:letter=?; number:number=?; letter:letter=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want a formula to check if two cells from different columns are numbers or not. I will assume that you want a `TRUE` result if both cells are numbers, and `FALSE` otherwise. This is the formula that fits those requirements:

```
=AND((IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A), "TRUE", "FALSE"))="TRUE",(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B), "TRUE", "FALSE"))="TRUE")
```

I have used the same `IF(ISNUMBER())` structure as your example. I only added the [`AND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) function to join both checks together. That function returns `TRUE` if every check inside it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you. This is almost identical to what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to count it you can do:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(FLATTEN(A:B);
       NOT(ISNUMBER(FLATTEN(A:B))); 
       NOT( ISBLANK(FLATTEN(A:B))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about flatten. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
=COUNTIF(A:B,"><")
```

[image]

Norwegian Sheets - so change ";" with ","

Comment: If you want just TRUE or FALSE - include IF: =IF(COUNTIF(A2:B;"><")>0;TRUE;FALSE)